# Is there a global Start() and Stop() API in Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-lifecycle

So, I have an Android application. I have.. let's say a Menu > About button on multiple screens or something. I want to keep track of how often a user will push it and when they exit the application, I want to send that count to a remote server. When they start the application again, I need to reset that count to 0.

So far, I imagine some simple static class

```
public static class ButtonCounter
{
  static int Count;
  public static void Start()
  {
    Count=0;
  }
  public static void Increment()
  {
    Count++;
  }
  public static void Stop()
  {
    //send to server
  }
}
```

Now, the hard part is that I somehow need to globally insert the `Start` and `Stop` methods into each activity's `OnStart` and `OnStop` method... And even then it'd still require something else so that `Stop` isn't called when you advance from one screen of the application to the next.

Basically, somehow, I want for `Stop` to only be called when it is leaving the code I *own* (ie, obscuring the activity, and moving to an activity not within this application).. and I want `Start` to only be called when it is entering the code I own AND leaving foreign (not my application) code.

I know my wish is probably not possible with how Android's life cycle for everything works.. but can someone nudge me in what would be the right direction on how to do this most effectively?

(also, I tagged Xamarin, but it should equally apply to standard Java code as well)

Comment: not sure if the best approach but you could maintain a let's say boolean member that goes true when the Activity is actually being used, and then when your activity calls `onStop()` you check all activities boolean, if all of them are false, then the user left your code, if any is true then is a let's call it `inner onStop()` call, same with `onStart()`, not so elegant approach, but i think it could work.

Comment: The thing is that I would much rather not have to duplicate this kind of code in each activity

Comment: well, you could do a "helper" class that encapsulate that behaviour and reuse it anywhere you need it

Comment: im actually seeing, the new boolean member, and the `ItLeavesOrNotMyApp` class.

Comment: You mean Application or a component like service, activity or event boardcast?

Comment: and by the way, i would rather use `SharedPreferences` or directly a internal storage `File` that would be created when the app start and erased at `onDestroy()` or `finish()` or when the user `leaves` my app, i just see it as a better approach, still the static class would do the work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep track of certain features that the user does throughout using an application, and not have to develop them yourself there are options available for you.  I am not precisely sure from the question if this is the case.  But there are certain APIs available for use for you, where you can just put a couple lines of code in at various places to keep track of stuff like this for you.

One such solution would be to use a service such as this one here: [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/).  With a service such as this, the work is pretty much done for you for.  If you are only interested in developing one yourself, feel free to ignore this response.  When using this one myself, it was pretty simple.  I just initialize a Flurry variable and then tell it that I want a click here or a function call there to be tracked.

Comment: mmm.. I won't be able to use that.. I am very interested in how such a thing works behind the scenes though

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create a custom base class that extends Activity and have all of your activities extend that base class.

```
public class MyMonitoredActivity:Activity{
    ....
    protected override void OnStart ()
    {
        base.OnStart();
        ButtonCounter.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop ()
    {
        base.OnStop();
        ButtonCounter.Stop();

    }
}
```

You could then add any sort of boolean checks or what not like @JosephChilberry suggested.